# How can I check for basename (only part of the name) file existence using Python?

Tags: python, filenames, partial, exists

I think the title explains it all. I need to check existence for a file that contains the word `data` in its name. I tried something like that `os.path.exists(/d/prog/*data.txt)` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You can't just do it with `os.path.exists` -- it expects full pathname. If do not know exact filename, you should first find this file on filesystem (and when you do, it proves that file exists).

One option is to list directory (-ies), and find file manually:

```
>>> import os
>>> file_list = os.listdir('/etc')
>>> [fn for fn in file_list if 'deny' in fn]
['hostapd.deny', 'at.deny', 'cron.deny', 'hosts.deny']
```

Another and more flexible option is to use [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html), which allows to use wildcards such as `*`, `?` and `[...]`:

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob('/etc/*deny*')
['/etc/hostapd.deny', '/etc/at.deny', '/etc/cron.deny', '/etc/hosts.deny']
```

Answer (score 3):

Try [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.glob) for it:

```
from glob import glob
if glob('/d/prog/*data.txt'):
    # blah blah
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows:

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob('D:\\test\\*data*')
['D:\\test\\data.1028.txt', 'D:\\test\\data2.1041.txt']
```